# Error in bnlearn: variable has 5 levels but I get the error " variable arb_review must have at least two levels."

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

My data consists of 3 factor variables each with 5 levels.
`head(swiss_bn,n = 10)`

```
A tibble: 10 × 3
    arb_review blocks  stops
        <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1  exploratory  [1,2]  (0,2]
2  exploratory  (3,5]  (0,2]
3  exploratory  (2,3]  (0,2]
4  exploratory  [1,2]  (0,2]
5  exploratory  [1,2]      0
6  exploratory  (3,5]  (2,4]
7  exploratory  (3,5]  (0,2]
8  exploratory  (2,3]  (0,2]
9  disoriented (5,23] (4,18]
10 disoriented (5,23] (4,18]

nlevels(swiss_bn$arb_review)

[1] 5
```

But When I run

```
library(bnlearn)
hc(swiss_bn)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in check.data(x) : variable arb_review must have at least two levels.
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error with the example you posted. Everything works for me. Share a dataset that reproduces the error.

Comment: Use a data.frame not a tibble.